# For same api gson is working but jackson cannot parse the repsonse, returning a null value to the variables

Tags: java, android, jackson, gson

I am using Jackson converter factory for parsing, it returning null in response. But for the same api when I just used replced jackson converter Factory with gson, its working fine.

Json Response :

```
{
  "Politician_list": [

    {
      "Manifestos": [
        {
          "agenda": "All together",
          "document_url": "http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2014/03/14/article-2581407-1C4D453500000578-736_306x352.jpg",
          "id": 2,
          "tagline": "Hathi ke sath",
          "targets": "literacy"
        }
      ],
      "Projects": [
        {
          "end_date": "20 January 2016",
          "id": 1,
          "project_details": "Reservoir construction",
          "project_image": "http://static.progressivemediagroup.com/uploads/imagelibrary/nri/water/floridaresproj.jpg",
          "start_date": "20 November 2015"
        },
        {
          "end_date": "13 February 2015",
          "id": 2,
          "project_details": "Dam construction",
          "project_image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/ee/Tarbela_Dam,_KPK,_Pakistan.jpg",
          "start_date": "18 June 2014"
        }
      ],
      "address_data": {
        "address": "207 maitry",
        "city": "gurgaon",
        "country": "India",
        "landmark": "Home",
        "lat": "542354",
        "lon": "2345",
        "pincode": "122011",
        "state": "Haryana"
      },
      "age": 42,
      "assets": "Rs 3,27,05,761",
      "back_image_url": "http://www.palpalindia.com/2015/03/08/bulandshahr-UP-Human-Welfare-Committee-Jehangirabad-B-Chandrakala-SSP-Dev-Tiwari-news-in-hindi-india-87165.jpg",
      "birth_place": "Allahabad",
      "criminal_cases": 0,
      "current_party": "BSP",
      "current_position": "Member of Legislative Assembly",
      "dob": "14 January 1975",
      "education_qual": "Literate",
      "father_name": "Ranveer Singh",
      "gender": "M",
      "id": 1,
      "image_url": "http://newsratingpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Gajendra-Singh-BSP-UP-Anupshahr-167x171.jpg",
      "income": "Rs 6,84,202",
      "liabilities": "Rs 21,16,000",
      "marital_status": "Married",
      "mother_name": "Shanti",
      "name": "Gajendra Singh",
      "no_of_child": 3,
      "spouse_name": "Anita Singh"
    }
  ],
  "response": "success"
}
```

When I used Jackson Converter Factory in retrofit 2, politician list returning me null but string response shows a 'success', but when I used Gson Converter Facrtory in retrofit 2, its working just fine.

Politician Main Response :

```
private List<DemographyPoliticianDetails> Politician_list;

private String response;
```

DemographyPoliticianDetails class :

```
private int age;
private String assets;
private String birth_place;
private int criminal_cases;
private String current_position;
private String current_party;
private String dob;
private String education_qual;
private String father_name;
private String mother_name;
private String name;
private String gender;
private String image_url;
private int id;
private String income;
private String marital_status;
private String liabilities;
private int no_of_child;
private String spouse_name;
private String back_image_url;


private AddressDataModel address_data;
private List<ProjectsModel> Projects;
private List<ManifestoModel> Manifestos;
```

Comment: Jackson uses different annotations from gson.. Have you changed that?  Post your POJO

Comment: sorry for late reply, I have added that in the ques

Comment: No I meant the model for the Json object response. Containing `Politician_list` and other keys

Comment: If you are checking the variable names, I have checked. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see in your POJO that you have created some variables with inital capital letter and maybe Jackson converter factory while converting the JSON response face some issues regarding inflating the POJO object assuming that in java the variable name start with small case.

for instance variable name of Politician_list should be politician_list*

- should follow the java naming convention of first letter small.